# BeautifulSoup email extraction not working

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wrote a basic script to extract email from web page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

def get_email(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'x-runtime': '148ms'}, allow_redirects=True).content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

    email = soup(text=re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z]+[\w\-.]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+[a-zA-Z]')) # this is working with

    print ("email ",email)


get_email('http://www.aberdeenweddingshop.co.uk/contact-us')
get_email('http://www.foodforthoughtdeli.co.uk/contact.htm')

OUTPUT:  
email  info@aberdeenweddingshop.co.uk
email  [] <------------------------#should give info@foodforthoughtdeli.co.uk
```

It is giving correct result for first URL but not fetching anything in second URL. I dont know the reason. I tried changing the regex also. I verified regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/pS7iR7/8) but due to some reason it is not working in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first case the e-mail is a text from a single span. On your second case the e-mail is in a `p` element that has more text than your e-mail.

Your regex won't match on your second because you are searching at the begining of the string and for characters that aren't valid in the given context.

You'll have to find your email **in** a string and then extract it.
Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

def get_email(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'x-runtime': '148ms'}, allow_redirects=True).content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

    email = soup(text=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*'))

    _emailtokens = str(email).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "").split(' ')

    if len(_emailtokens):
        print([match.group(0) for token in _emailtokens for match in [re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", str(token.strip()))] if match])


get_email('http://www.aberdeenweddingshop.co.uk/contact-us')
get_email('http://www.foodforthoughtdeli.co.uk/contact.htm')
```

Outputs:

> ['info@aberdeenweddingshop.co.uk']
>
> ['info@foodforthoughtdeli.co.uk']

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a match with the second URL is due to the caret (`^`) requiring that the regular expression be at the start. When the caret is omitted, the following is obtained:

```
>>> soup(text=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+[\w\-.]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+[a-zA-Z]'))
['E-mail: \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tinfo@foodforthoughtdeli.co.uk\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
```

Since we’re using regular expressions to match a string in the response, we’re not really using the good parts of Beautiful Soup and it can be omitted altogether:

```
def get_email(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'x-runtime': '148ms'}, allow_redirects=True).content
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, allow_redirects=True).text
    email_address = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+[\w\-.]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+[a-zA-Z]', response).group()
    print(email_address)
```

Note: I used the `text` attribute of the response object to work on a string representation — rather than the stream of bytes that are returned using the `content` attribute.